# For all polyomial $P$ in $\mathbb C[X]$ there exists a norm such that $(X^n)$ tends to $P$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, polynomials, normed-spaces

Show that for all $P$ in $\mathbb C[X]$ there exists a norm such that $(X^n)$ tends to $P$.

I post my answer, if someone has another approach...

Comment: What's $\mathbb{C}[X]$?

Comment: The set of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb C$. What is the english notation ?

Comment: Your notation is fine

Comment: Your notation is fine, I'm just more used to seeing it with a lower case $x$, instead of $X$, plus I'm not used to seeing $\mathbb{C}[x]$ treated as a normed space, so I was unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Spoil

> Let $d$ be the degree of $P$. Consider the basis $(1, X, ... X^d,X^{d+1}-P, X^{d+2} -P, ... $ and the norm such that $||Q||$ = $\sup(\frac{|a_j|}{2^j})$ with the $a_j$ be the coefficients of $Q$ in this basis.  Then, for $n >d$, $||X^n - P|| = \frac{1}{2^n} \to 0$

<